# How to perform changes on Core Data set without iterating the results?

Tags: objective-c, sql, cocoa-touch, core-data, sql-update

If `NSFetchRequest` is the Core Data equivalent of an SQL query containing `SELECT`, is there a Core Data equivalent of the SQL command `UPDATE`?

Or in other words, if I want to change values on a Core Data set, is there **a way around iterating over the results** of an `NSFetchRequest`?

In case you're answering with 'no', I'd very much appreciate some kind of reference documentation. Cheers!

**EDIT:** By 'iteration' I mean that I know how to for-loop over the entities and changes values:

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:...];
for (NSManagedObject *object in results) {
    object.value = anotherValue;
}
```

But if they're all getting the same value on the same property, I'd just like to call something like `[context executeChangesOnFetchRequest:...]`. Of course this method does not exist, but maybe there is a more elegant/concise way than the for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no. If you want changes to be made on the object context in which the Core Data objects reside, you must set the respective properties on said objects and then commit the changes on that object context. Core Data will handle all the optimizations for you.

If you're simply looking for a way to avoid a `for` loop to update properties on objects in the result set, you can try using `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`.

```
NSFetchRequest *req = ...;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
if(error != nil) {
  //oops.
} else {
   //avoid the loop:
   [results makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setSomeProperty:) withObject:someValue];

   if(![self.managedObjectContext save:nil]) {
      //error during save
   }
}
```

**For the adventurous, you can try adding a category on `NSManagedObjectContext`**:

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext (JRAdditions)

- (BOOL) executeChanges:(NSDictionary *) changes 
       withFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *) request
                  error:(NSError **) error;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (JRAdditions)

- (BOOL) executeChanges:(NSDictionary *) changes 
       withFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *) request
                  error:(NSError **) error {

   NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
   if(*error || ![results count]) return NO;

   [results makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:)
                            withObject:changes];
   return [self save:error];
}

@end
```

You could then call this like so:

```
NSDictionary *changes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
NSFetchRequest *request = ...;
NSError *error = nil;

if([self.managedObjectContext executeChanges:changes withFetchRequest:request error:&error]) {
   //done.
} else {
   //error.
}
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for your time man. This is the solution I call "iterating over the results" which I'm trying to find a way around, if it exists...

Comment: @epologee Well, you have to set the property on all of the objects in the returned `NSArray`.

Comment: @epologee See updated, maybe that helps? I'm assuming you have to "reset" the data back to some initial state or something?

Comment: I know. But with a sequel language one could instantly perform the changes without first having to perform a select. Like `UPDATE key=value FROM table`. I know I can do the iteration, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way to perform a large batch of changes if they're all getting the same value anyway.

Comment: @epologee Core Data does this for you automatically. You don't need to worry about that. The changes are queued up and not actually committed to the underlying SQLite database until the call to `save:`

Comment: What is "iterating over the results" and what is the problem with it? I can modify a single entity and save it like Jacob suggested. How is that "iterating"? I don't understand.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know the `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` method yet. That's one step up already.

Comment: @epologee This doesn't necessarily improve performance. It might make it cleaner, though.

Comment: @JacobRelkin yes, one step up, but not quite on top of the flight yet :)

Comment: @epologee Frankly, I think this is premature optimization. Core Data is already doing everything you want it to do. It makes that `UPDATE` query for you.

Comment: In your category, you don't declare your error, so it won't compile. EDIT: Nevermind, I see it now, but shouldn't you be passing it in by reference?